# No data being returned from syncfusion querybuilder

Tags: syncfusion, ej2-syncfusion

I have a dataset that I want to build a query tool for so not being a web developer I turned to Syncfusion's `QueryBuilder`.

Using the exact code displayed [here](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/vue/documentation/query-builder/data-binding/#local-data) in their tutorial of local data for the `App.vue` and `datasource.js`.  I made my webpage, when when entering conditions no data is returned to me. How can I get the data to be return when querying it?

Answer (score 0):

We have checked your reported query. We have prepared Querybuilder sample using local data as demonstrated in the below code snippet.

```
App.vue

<template>
  <div class="control-section">
    <div class="col-lg-12 querybuilder-control">
      <ejs-querybuilder
        width="70%"
        :rule="importRules"
        :dataSource="dataSource"
      >
      </ejs-querybuilder>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import Vue from "vue";
import {
  QueryBuilderPlugin,
  dataSource,
} from "@syncfusion/ej2-vue-querybuilder";
Vue.use(QueryBuilderPlugin);
import { employeeData } from "/src/dataSource.js";

export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
      dataSource: employeeData,
      values: ["Mr.", "Mrs."],
      importRules: {
        condition: "and",
        rules: [
          {
            label: "Employee ID",
            field: "EmployeeID",
            type: "number",
            operator: "equal",
            value: 1,
          },
          {
            label: "Title",
            field: "Title",
            type: "string",
            operator: "equal",
            value: "Sales Manager",
          },
        ],
      },
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

For your reference, we have prepared a sample based on your requirement. Please check the below sample.

Sample: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-forked-g62vv?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: I am still not getting any data returned when entering variables into the fields. I am really not sure what I am doing wrong. In your `codesandbox` snippet I also see no data being returned.